# DataTable Position fixed

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatable, datatables

Look at this Picture . my Jquery DataTable Covered my Navigation Bar..
[Picture](https://imageshack.com/i/p6WLrHifj)
[This Picture](https://imageshack.com/i/ezkXvgplj)

i want my Navigation bar on the top how to set this?

Comment: "_how to set this?_" - How should anyone could answer without guessing? :) Post some code and create a fiddle or link to the site.

Comment: Looks like a CSS issue to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS
z-index: 99;

because the z-index of datatable is higher than on my NavBar.